# What is the best way to transfer files between an ASP.NET site and a PHP site?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have a web-site, based on ASP.NET, hosted at provider x.
For various reasons, I would like to keep all image files, uploaded by the users, on another site hosted a provider y.
Provider y is PHP based.

What would be the best way to transfer the images from my ASP.NET site on x to the "PHP Store" at provider y? The images come in on the ASP.NET site via web-services and "manual" file uploads.

It is only a "problem" when storing the images, on read the image urls will of course just point to the location on y.

I guess the only way is to create a web-service in PHP that I can call at y with my image from x, but are there other better ways? And if not does, anyone know a link to an example of the required ASP.NET and PHP code for that web-service setup?

Comment: Just send raw data in a POST request to PHP.

Comment: Questions which ask for the best way to do x are often considered off topic on SO. And will often get closed as "not constructive". This is because the fact there are often multiple ways to get to a certain solution and with the provided info it would have been hard to give a exact and correct answer. Also the last part of you question basically asks (or at least reads like it asks): "give me the code please". On this site we expect answers to be specific. In its current form the question was just too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you all suggested, the way to do it is with web-services.
I couldn't find a clear example how to do it on both ends (ASP.NET and PHP) so here is what I ended up with, and it Works.

PHP File

```
<?php
$target_path =  "uploadfolder/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "OK";
} else{
    echo "ERROR ".$target_path;
}
?>
```

This is what I have on the ASP.NET side:

```
    private void UploadFile(string postUrl, string postFilename)
    {
        WebClient wb = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            byte[] responseArray = wb.UploadFile(postUrl, postFilename);
            string resp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseArray);
            // You can read the response (resp) and check if you get an OK or ERROR from the PHP
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            // Do stuff based on the exception
        }
    }
```

Usage: UploadFile("http://www.domain.com/thephpscript.php",FileUpload1.FileName);

It was pure luck that I guessed that when you use the .NET WebClient.UploadFile method it names the file as 'file' which you need to know in the  $_FILES associative array on the PHP side.
That's the primary reason I posted this, so I hope another kind soul won't have to guess.

Of course you should take meassures to check what kind of files the user is uploading etc. but this is the basics.

Comment: Right what I was thinking... 
Do not forget to create some failure prevention and recovery logic, since a some moment the other server can be unavailable, for any reason, and you'll need to schedule the delivery to be repeated in the future.

Comment: @svrx That is a good point, and valuable input for others too see as well. I will create a "queue system" for images that must be sent again later if they fail. This will also ease maintenance, when we need to deploy updates, or even move the PHP site to another place.

Answer (score 1):

Just send raw data in a POST request…

The php page will insure that the file is from an approved source, capture it, and process it. (Because the source is only one particular web site, perhaps it’s safe to allow all from the source IP addr of the web site

```
Ideas on how to best accomplish this?
```

On the requesting (ASP.Net) side, you will need to use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes.  On the responding (PHP) side, it’s not going to be any different from handling a form submission.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that when you say a Web Service, you are referring to a simple REST Web Service, which consists in a PHP page that parses the posted data and store it in a proper location.

If i am right yes that seem like a good way to do the image submission to server Y. 
If not and you refer to a proper SOAP/XML Web Service, I think that there is no need to use such advanced approaches only to accomplish this simples task.

In brief you need only to use a `WebClient` to make a POST `WebRequest` containing the image data at the ASP.NET server side. At the PHP side you will receive the posted data and be able to do whatever you want with it.

This is the simplest approach, but depending on the size of the files transfered and nature of the task there other alternatives such as:
- If the files to be transfered are big or there is no need to transfer the files synchronously, you can use the FTP protocol, both using ad-hoc or integrated solution depending on your requirements;

Comment: Yes, that was what I thought - a simple PHP script to handle the image. The files are small (max 100 KB each) and needs to be transferred instantly, so I guess it is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished by using webservice at PHP end to save a file which is posted as `byte[]`

In ASP.NET send the file as below:-

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string spath = Server.MapPath("" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(spath);
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(spath);
        long numBytes = fInfo.Length;
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(spath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);
        byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        br.Close();
        string result = src.UploadFile(data, FileUpload1.FileName);
        fStream.Close();
        fStream.Dispose();
}
```

Class src is used to send the data i.e. consume the web service at PHP server which will save the data as file with its filename.

Comment: I get the ASP file read part, but I would like to see what you do in the src class. I mean where to put the byte[] before the post.

Comment: in php create a service say uploadfile(byte[] f , string filename) which will take raw byte[] and its filename as parameter.
when you will add this service as reference in your asp.net vs will take care to serealize your byte[] it self. However if you want to do it yourself then you will have to use streams.